# Prove that event will happen an infinite number of times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I want to prove that if $X_n$ is sequence of collectively independent exponential random variables and $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = 1$ than $$\text{event }\{X_n\le\ln{n}+\ln{\ln{n}}+\ln^2{\ln{\ln{n}}}\}\text{ will happen an infinite number of times.}$$ May somebody can help me? I would be grateful.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the event $X_n \le \mathbb E(X_n)$ will happen infinitely often, given the i.i.d. condition. For large enough $n$ you have $\mathbb E(X_n) \lt \ln{n} \lt \ln{n}+\ln{\ln{n}}+\ln^2{\ln{\ln{n}}}$.  So you do not need the exponential distribution: all you need is that the expectation is finite.

Comment: Even the event $X_n\le 1$ happens infinitely often, as does any sequence of independent events with the same probability. Presumably you mean to say $\{X_n\ge \ln n+\ln \ln n+\ln^2\ln \ln n\}$ happens i.o.?

Comment: But it turns out $P(X_n\ge \ln n + \ln \ln n+\ln^2\ln \ln n\;\;\text{i.o.})=0$, so letting $E_n$ be that event, instead of asking for $P(E_n\;\;\text{i.o.})$, it is much more interesting to ask $P(E_n\;\;\text{eventually})$, i.e. the probability that $E_n$ only fails to occur finitely many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  simple application of Borel Cantelli Lemma. If $\sum P(X_n \leq a_n)=\infty$ then $X_n \leq a_n$ holds infinitely often with probability $1$. So you only have to check that $\sum [1-e^{-(\ln n+ \ln \ln n +\ln^{2} \ln \ln n)}]=\infty$. Can you check this? [The general term of this series does not tend to $0$].

Comment: But how to show that the main term of the series does not tend to 0?

Comment: If $c_n \to \infty$ then $1-e^{-c_n} \to 1-0=1 \neq 0$. @NickNiceday

Comment: Thank you very mach!